# How to know if connection is established in rxjs webSocket?

Tags: javascript, websocket, rxjs

Using `rxjs` [webSocket](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/webSocket/webSocket) here (at least trying to) and have a question - how does one know if connection is established? Is there any way to query the instance for its current state?

Answer (score 2):

There are configuration you can create to pass in a open or close connection observer

https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/webSocket/WebSocketSubjectConfig

import { webSocket } from 'rxjs/webSocket';

```
const wsSubject = webSocket({
    url: 'ws://localhost:8081',
    openObserver: {
        next: () => {
            console.log('connetion ok');
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I know that part, and I have a wrapper that sets a corresponding flag `onopen` and unsets `onclose`. But it feels redundant, as the flasg should be in the `webSocket` itself.

Comment: I suggest to pass in subject as observer so you can just subscribe to that subject for onclose event, and compose the subject to whatever socket stream u have. Using book flag isn’t quite functional approach